# can I put a single mixer tap in a basin that has 3 holes?

Tags: taps

Can I put a single mixer tap in a basin that has 3 holes? I've just bought a basin that has 3 holes. Can I put a single mixer in the centre one and plug the other 2 holes? I notice that the centre hole is smaller than the outer two.
Thanks!

Comment: Smaller center hole could be an issue. Making the hole larger could be a project.

Answer (score 3):

Probably.

Will it look good?  Maybe.

Some single hole kitchen faucets have an escutcheon plate that will cover a standard 8 inch,  3 hole to allow you you mount a single hole.

[image]